# How can I customize the creation of my Service Manifest file?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When I add a new Actor to my Service Fabric project, the Service is automatically added to my **ApplicationManifest.xml** and **ServiceManifest.xml** files because we have **UpdateServiceFabricManifestEnabled** set to true. For certain projects, we need to require services to have **PlacementConstraints** so they're deployed to the proper node.

How do I hook into this process so that I can specify the **PlacementConstraints** without having to remember to edit any of the manifest files?

Comment: Placement constraints are part of the service manifest.  What do you need to edit in the application manifest?

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to answer that @MattThalman :) I didn't realize that PlacementConstraints were in the ServiceManifest.xml file (still learning lots). So I believe my question should be asking about ServiceManifest instead of ApplicationManifest. However, when I add them in the project's ServiceManifest, the build doesn't include them in the ApplicationManifest.

Comment: Doesn't include _what_ in the app manifest?  The placement constraints?  They're not supposed to be in the app manifest.  I'm not sure I understand where the issue is.

Comment: Maybe a better question is: When I deploy, I need to add PlacementConstraints. I can't find much documentation on how we should be doing this.

Comment: So you want placement constraints to be added to your service manifest automatically as part of your build process?

Comment: Yes, I would like it to include placement constraints in the process that generates the xml for me. I don't want to have to edit the xml by hand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109842/discussion-between-chris-missal-and-matt-thalman).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The service manifest file gets automatically populated with the actor service types as part of the build.  There's an MSBuild target that gets run after the built-in "Build" target which does this.  You can tack on your own logic that gets run after this.  In that logic, you can make any necessary changes to the service manifest file.  Here's an example that ensures that placement constraints are added to all the service types in the service manifest file.  It uses an inline MSBuild task but you could rewrite this to be contained in a compiled assembly or whatever you wanna do.

This sample should be placed at the end of the file in your Actor service project:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="EnsurePlacementConstraints" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll">
  <ParameterGroup>
    <ServiceManifestPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
  </ParameterGroup>
  <Task>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Using Namespace="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
    <![CDATA[
const string FabricNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2011/01/fabric";
XDocument serviceManifest = XDocument.Load(ServiceManifestPath);
IEnumerable<XElement> serviceTypes = serviceManifest.Root.Element(XName.Get("ServiceTypes", FabricNamespace)).Elements();
bool changesMade = false;
foreach (XElement serviceType in serviceTypes)
{
  XName placementConstraintsName = XName.Get("PlacementConstraints", FabricNamespace);
  if (serviceType.Element(placementConstraintsName) == null)
  {
    XElement placementConstraints = new XElement(placementConstraintsName);
    placementConstraints.Value = "(add your contraints here)";
    serviceType.AddFirst(placementConstraints);
    changesMade = true;
  }
}

if (changesMade)
{
    serviceManifest.Save(ServiceManifestPath);
}
    ]]>
    </Code>
  </Task>
</UsingTask>

<Target Name="EnsurePlacementConstraints" AfterTargets="Build">   
  <EnsurePlacementConstraints ServiceManifestPath="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\PackageRoot\ServiceManifest.xml" />
</Target>
```